# NivoSlider error

Tags: javascript, nivo-slider

I use `NivoSlider` and I want to stop it after load (to start it manually).

I use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider1').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            slices: 15, // For slice animations
            boxCols: 8, // For box animations
            boxRows: 4, // For box animations
            animSpeed: 800, // Slide transition speed
            pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
            startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
            directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
            controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
            controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            pauseOnHover: false, // Stop animation while hovering
            manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
            paused:true,
            afterLoad: function(){
            $('#slider1').data('nivoSlider').stop();
 }
        });
    });

</script>
```

But I get the
`Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined.`

Comment: Seems that nivoSlader doesn't store at data. What context you have in ```afterLoad``` function. Make ```console.log(this, arguments)``` in ```afterLoad``` and print here output.

Comment: the output is ` 
t {stop: function, start: function}
start: function (){if(e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop){e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop=false;m("Start Slider")}}
stop: function (){if(!e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop){e(t).data("nivo:vars").stop=true;m("Stop Slider")}}
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Provide jsfiddle with code. Also why you not initialize nivo when you really need this?

Comment: Try call in ```afterLoad``` this ```this.stop()```.

Comment: I tried this.stop() and it works! Thanks a lot! But how can I start it in another script and avoid my previews error?

Comment: Try call ```nivoSlider()``` without config object. Or bind event in ```afterLoad``` that will call ```this.start()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `afterLoad()` this context it's NivoSlider. So you can call just `this.stop()`.

```
afterLoad: function() {
    this.stop();
}
```